# How to separate SQL variable inside a string

Tags: sql, string, oracle, sqlplus

In my SQL script I can define variable like:

```
DEFINE x=100;
```

and use it like:

```
CREATE TABLE A&x AS ...;
```

the result will be `CREATE TABLE A100 AS ...` (concatenated string).

But I'd like to get `CREATE TABLE A100B AS ...` in similar query (B suffix):

```
CREATE TABLE A&xB AS ...;
```

But Oracle/SQL understands there is `xB` variable

How to separate variable (name) inside SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE A&{x}B AS ...;
```

This does not work!

(e.g. like `${x}` i PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a tiny, little **dot**.

```
SQL> define x=100
SQL> create table a&x.b as select * from dual;
old   1: create table a&x.b as select * from dual
new   1: create table a100b as select * from dual

Table created.

SQL> select * from a100b;

D
-
X

SQL>
```

Here, in case you missed it:

```
create table a&x.b
                ^
                |
               here
```

What's the point? The SQL*Plus **concatenation character**. By default, it is a dot. It tells SQL*Plus where the variable name ends.

---

If you ask for more help:

```
SQL> help set

 SET
 ---

 Sets a system variable to alter the SQL*Plus environment settings
 for your current session. For example, to:
     -   set the display width for data
     -   customize HTML formatting
     -   enable or disable printing of column headings
     -   set the number of lines per page

 SET system_variable value

 where system_variable and value represent one of the following clauses:

   APPI[NFO]{OFF|ON|text}                   NEWP[AGE] {1|n|NONE}
   ARRAY[SIZE] {15|n}                       NULL text
   AUTO[COMMIT] {OFF|ON|IMM[EDIATE]|n}      NUMF[ORMAT] format
   <snip>
   ---------------------
   CON[CAT] {.|c|ON|OFF}                      [FOR[MAT]  {WRA[PPED] |
   ---------------------
   Here it is!
```

Comment: That's because the OP & me live in the same country so I understood them better, @GMB :)

Comment: Ha, ha, local understanding. Zahvaljujem. Pivica uvijek može kad si za.

Comment: Nema na čemu, dogovoreno :)